# Not all ngOnInit instructions are executed

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**Explain:**
 1. I have this: src/assets/js/runDoe.js  (runDoe contains a Immediately Invoked Function Expression)
 2. Body to my index.html (project in Angular):

```html
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <app-doe></app-doe>
</body>
```

3. In the component doe:

```
import ...
import {runDoe} from '../../assets/js/runDoe.js';
export class DoeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private doeService: DoeService) {console.log('constructor');}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('ngOnInit');
    this.doeService.getDoe().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
    runDoe();
  }
}
```

**Problematic:**
The script is running correctly but console.log does not appear

**Question**
Why runDoe() works but absolutely no console.log is displayed

Comment: add your code for `DoeService`

Comment: Please add an [mcve] that replicates the issue. You can use https://stackblitz.com to create one and share the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because the Angular is not rendering the DoeComponent beacause in your module the bootstrap component is `AppComponent` with selector `app-root` so if you want to run the `ngOnInit` of the DoeComponent use its selector in AppComponent or any other subsequent component.

Comment: exactly ! thanks you
I transform doeComponent into doeDirective (dont need view) and call him in appComponent

Comment: Glad I could help!